How to fix duplicate id's in multiselect options
Via the api, multi select options were accidentally inserted as duplicates.
So instead of 11111,22222 being stored in catalog_product_entity_text.value it was submitted as 11111,22222,11111,22222 and stored as such.
This causes the indexer to break with duplicate errors.
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:    
1062 Duplicate entry '681306-12156-1-7638991-681306' for key 'PRIMARY',   
query was:   
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_index_eav_temp`    
(`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`,`source_id`)    
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)......


To solve the issue with duplicate values after resolving the endpoint submitting the wrong data, without having to synchronize all the products anew you can run the following query on the database
-- if a query went wrong the temp table may still exist, so drop it again.
DROP temporary table if exists temp_item_extraction;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_item_extraction AS
SELECT
    catalog_product_entity_text.value_id,
    catalog_product_entity_text.value,
    -- Extract each item from the comma-separated list, return NULL if index exceeds count of commas
    CASE WHEN 0 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 1), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS first_item,
    CASE WHEN 1 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 2), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS second_item,
    CASE WHEN 2 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 3), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS third_item,
    CASE WHEN 3 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 4), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS fourth_item,
    CASE WHEN 4 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 5), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS fifth_item,
    CASE WHEN 5 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 6), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS sixth_item,
    CASE WHEN 6 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 7), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS seventh_item,
    CASE WHEN 7 <= CHAR_LENGTH(catalog_product_entity_text.value) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', '')) THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog_product_entity_text.value, ',', 8), ',', -1) ELSE NULL END AS eighth_item
-- expand the above as much as needed, also then at the other parts where there are relevant selects referencing the items.
FROM
    catalog_product_entity_text
        JOIN
    eav_attribute ON catalog_product_entity_text.attribute_id = eav_attribute.attribute_id
WHERE
    -- only arrays backend models will have this issue.
    eav_attribute.backend_model = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend'
  -- If you have only a specific attribute you can narrow the query here.
  -- AND (eav_attribute.attribute_code LIKE 'aca_%' OR eav_attribute.attribute_code LIKE 'lar_%')
  AND catalog_product_entity_text.value LIKE '%,%';

DROP temporary table if exists temp_aggregated;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_aggregated (
                                                         value_id INT,
                                                         item VARCHAR(255)
);
-- This is to make the multi column results into a two column result set.
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, first_item AS item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE first_item IS NOT NULL and first_item <> '';
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, second_item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE second_item IS NOT NULL and second_item <> '';
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, third_item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE third_item IS NOT NULL and third_item <> '';
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, fourth_item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE fourth_item IS NOT NULL and fourth_item <> '';
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, fifth_item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE fifth_item IS NOT NULL and fifth_item <> '';
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, sixth_item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE sixth_item IS NOT NULL and sixth_item <> '';
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, seventh_item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE seventh_item IS NOT NULL and seventh_item <> '';
INSERT INTO temp_aggregated (value_id, item)
SELECT value_id, eighth_item FROM temp_item_extraction WHERE eighth_item IS NOT NULL and eighth_item <> '';
-- expand the above if you added extra items to your query.

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_unique;
-- This is to get all the distinct items, and group them by item(which can be duplicates, this squashes them)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_unique (
    value_id INT,
    item VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO temp_unique (item, value_id)
SELECT distinct item,value_id
FROM temp_aggregated
where item is not null and item <> ''
GROUP BY item, value_id;

-- If you wish to update the table to workable order run this update statement
-- else, only run the select statement to see the output.
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text AS cpet
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            value_id,
            TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(item SEPARATOR ','), ',,', ',')) AS item
        FROM
            temp_unique
        WHERE
            item IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY
            value_id
    ) AS updated_values
    ON cpet.value_id = updated_values.value_id
SET cpet.value = updated_values.item;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_unique;
DROP temporary table if exists temp_aggregated;
DROP temporary table if exists temp_item_extraction;

